# Approach for parent child relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have following entities in my database:

1. Folder
2. Set
3. Group
4. Item

An Item is related to only one Group. However A group can belong to a folder or set which in turn can belong to either folder or set.
Something like this

Item1->Group1

Group1->Folder1->Folder2
Group2->Set1->Folder3

I am trying to map this to relational database in SQL server.

This is how I am mapping currently

Separate tables for each 
 1. Folder
 2. Set
 3. Group
 4. Item

Item table will have ParentId as Group ID

However I will have one more Table ParentChildMapping which will have

ChildID ParentID (either of them can map to any of FolderID, SetID or GroupID)

Is this a good approach or is there any better approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an entity-subtyping approach for Folder/Set/Group and use a recursive one-to-many relationship to record the parent/child relationship at the entity-supertype level.

This might look something like this:

```
Table: Container (super-type)
- ContainerID PK
- ParentContainerID NULL FK (to self)

Table: Folder (subtype)
- ContainerID PK FK
- (other folder columns)

Table: Set (subtype)
- ContainerID PK FK
- (other set columns)

Table: Group (subtype)
- ContainerID PK FK
- (other group columns)

Table: Item
- ItemID
- (other item columns)
- ContainerID (FK to GROUP)
```